# how to updates and synchronize all workers task and code

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

i have celery running on few computers and using flower for monitoring.
the computers is used by different people.
celery beat is generating jobs for all the workers from one of the computer.
every time new coded task is ready, all the workers less the beat-computer will have task not registered exception.
what is the recommended direction to sync all the code to all other computers in the network, is there a prehook kind of mechanism in celery to check for new code?
[image: ks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to update the code on all the workers (nodes) and after that you need to restart all of them. This is by (good) design.

A clever systemd service could in theory be able to

- send the graceful shutdown signal
- run pip install -U your-project
- start the Celery service